# How to convert JSON to XML with namespace?

Tags: python, json, xml

Please suggest me how to convert the JSON object to XML

Expectation,

From JSON,

```
{
    "Multiply": {
        "intA": 5, "intB": 5
    }
}
```

To XML,

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <Multiply xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <intA>5</intA>
        <intB>5</intB>
    </Multiply>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: achieved using the library xmltodict unparse method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider XSLT 3.0 (available to Python users via Saxon/C).

```
<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template" expand-text="yes">
  <xsl:variable name="json" select="json-doc('my.json')"/>
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                 xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
      <Multiply xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
        <intA>{$json?Multiply?IntA}</intA>
        <intB>{$json?Multiply?IntB}</intB>
      </Multiply>
    </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>
```

The advantage of this approach, compared with off-the-shelf json-to-xml conversion tools, is that it gives you total control over the XML output. (And of course you can go in the other direction as well).

Comment: thank you Micheal Key can you please refer me the documentation link since I cannot find any.

Comment: XSLT 3.0 - masses of information available, the spec is at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/ For the Saxon/C implementation, http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/index.xml